# HTML does not render with state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project where I have to display cards and reorder them every time the `SelectCard` function is clicked. The problem is that after the function is clicked and the `setPictures` method successfully updates the `pictures` variable, the HTML does not render the new values.

I've already tried creating a different ID every time `pictures` is reordered, but I still get the same result.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/main.css';
import HarryPotter from '../images/Harry-Potter.png';
import AlbusDumbledore from '../images/Albus-Dumbledore.jpg';
import BellatrixLestrange from '../images/Bellatrix-Lestrange.png';
import Boddy from '../images/Dobby.png';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

function Main(){
    var arrPictures = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Harry Potter",
            src: HarryPotter
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Albus Dumbledore",
            src: AlbusDumbledore,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Bellatrix Lestrange",
            src: BellatrixLestrange,
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Boddy",
            src: Boddy,
        },
    ];
    const [score, setScore]=useState(0);
    const [highest, setHighest]=useState(0);
    const [pictures, setPictures]=useState(arrPictures);   
    function shuffleArray(arr) {
        for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
        }
        return arr;
    }
    async function SelectCard(){
        const arr = shuffleArray(pictures);
        await setPictures(arr);
        console.log(pictures);
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <div id="score">
                <p>Current score: { score }</p>
                <p>Highest score: { highest }</p>
            </div>
            <div id="instructions">
                <p>Click to select a different card each round.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="cards">
                {pictures.map((picture) => (
                    <div className="card" key={ picture.id } onClick={ SelectCard }>
                        <img src={ picture.src } alt="Harry Potter character."></img>
                        <p>{ picture.name }</p>
                    </div>
                   ))}
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your problem!

Your select card function should look like that

```js
function selectCard(){
  const arr = [...shuffleArray(pictures)];
  setPictures(arr);
}
```

Explanation: As an objects in JS is saved as links, React doesn't see the difference between your state changing as similar object is passed all time. You need to create new object to make state update.

P.S1 You don't need async function SelectCard and await inside it. Also, you should keep convention in naming functions and rename it to the selectCard.

P.S2 You don't need first two state at all (maybe you will work around it later, than it is okay). You can create just a variables :)

Hope it helps